# To trigger ON & OFF of an emergency light with external signal

Tags: trigger

I need to trigger ON an emergency lamp with a (1st signal) signal, and the lamp will be lighted up until the next (2nd signal) signal is received then the emergency lamp will go OFF. How could I do this? Thanks

Comment: What do the 'signals' comprise of?  A data stream, a specific voltage, a flag being raised?

Comment: Do you know what a Moore state machine is?

Answer (score 0):

A 'ratchet relay' and a momentary push button switch would do for the application.

[image]

A single push / release of the button would close the relay contact and a subsequent push / release would open it.